# Value different outside of class

Tags: c#, .net

In the code for my networked game, the client receives a message that a player entity is controlled by the user or solely by the server.

```
UserControlled = msg.ReadBoolean();
```

This variable is **set** in absolutely no other location other than when it is instantiated with a default value of false. I've double checked this with the "Find all references" feature in Visual C#. In addition, there is no local variable within the scope of this statement with the same name. I've found that within the scope of the statement above, everything is find and dandy; the variable is set to true as shown by printing it to the console directly afterwards. At this point, strange things happen. Any time the variable is referenced from outside my player's class, it correctly displays as true - but any time it is referenced from inside the player's code, it returns the default value that the Boolean was instantiated as; either true or false.

I'm clueless beyond measure as to the problem, and any information that would lead to the solution is much appreciated :)

If you'd like more code, I can certainly provide it. I just wasn't sure what else to include other than random references to the variable, so I decided to leave them out.

Thanks!

Edit for more code:

UserControlled is defined as a normal class-wide variable.

```
public bool UserControlled = false;
```

The method that sets the value:

```
public override void ParseUpdateMsg(NetIncomingMessage msg) 
        {
            switch (msg.ReadByte())
            {
                case 0: // positional message
                    //snip
                    break;
                case 1: // other info
                    // The following simply reads in the information
                    // I'm using Lidgren Network Library. It's extensively tested so I don't suspect that it's the issue
                    Speed = msg.ReadInt16();
                    Username = msg.ReadString();
                    UserControlled = msg.ReadBoolean();
                    MovingDir = msg.ReadString();
                    Health = msg.ReadInt16();
                    Hunger = msg.ReadInt16();
                    Mana = msg.ReadInt16();
                    // The following is simply debugging information to the screen
                    // As said above, UserControlled at this point is correctly displayed as True
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                    Console.WriteLine("--------------------------");
                    Console.WriteLine("Update message received!");
                    Console.WriteLine("ID: " + ID + "\tType: " + this.GetType().ToString());
                    Console.WriteLine("Speed: " + Speed);
                    Console.WriteLine("Username: " + Username);
                    Console.WriteLine("UserControlled: " + UserControlled);
                    Console.WriteLine("MovingDir: " + MovingDir);
                    Console.WriteLine("--------------------------");
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                    break;
            }
        }
```

The following is the client code which receives the message and passes it to the player entity to evaluate:

```
switch (msg.ReadInt16())
            {
                case 1:
                    // Entity message
                    switch (msg.ReadByte())
                    {
                        case 0: // Create entity
                            //snip
                            break;
                        case 1: // Update entity
                            int id1 = msg.ReadInt16();
                            Entities[id1].ParseUpdateMsg(msg); // the player entity is passed the information
                            // At this point, there is only one entity, and that is the player.
                            // More debug information. Still displayed correctly as true.
                            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Magenta;
                            Console.WriteLine("--------------------------");
                            Console.WriteLine("-analysis 1-");
                            Console.WriteLine("(Within scope of update-entity message)");
                            Console.WriteLine("UserControlled: " + ((ClientEntPlayer)Entities[id1]).UserControlled);
                            Console.WriteLine("--------------------------");
                            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                            break;
                        case 2: // Destroy entity
                            //snip
                            break;
                    }
                    // Displayed correctly here as well!
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Magenta;
                    Console.WriteLine("--------------------------");
                    Console.WriteLine("-Post-analysis 2-");
                    Console.WriteLine("(Within scope of generic entity message)");
                    Console.WriteLine("UserControlled: " + player.UserControlled);
                    Console.WriteLine("--------------------------");
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                    break;
            }
```

All debug code above is correctly displayed as True after the value is set. However, once we start getting into timed checking, it starts to become incorrect (but still only from the player's code!)

The following is from the client's update code. It displays correctly the UserControlled value every 5 seconds.

```
if (gameTime.TotalGameTime.Seconds % 5 == 0 && player != null && debugTime != gameTime.TotalGameTime.Seconds)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkMagenta;
                Console.WriteLine("--------------------------");
                Console.WriteLine("Client's Timed Post-Analysis");
                Console.WriteLine("Elapsed time: " + gameTime.TotalGameTime.Seconds + " sec");
                Console.WriteLine("(Within scope of client update)");
                Console.WriteLine("UserControlled: " + player.UserControlled);
                Console.WriteLine("--------------------------");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                debugTime = gameTime.TotalGameTime.Seconds;
            }
```

This is the part that shows the player's value is incorrect after the function is left. It displays false (and other code that relies on the player being controlled, like responding to keyboard input.) It's essentially the same code as the client's timed debug information, only instead it's inside of the player's update function.

```
if (gameTime.TotalGameTime.Seconds % 5 == 0 && debugTime != gameTime.TotalGameTime.Seconds)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkYellow;
                Console.WriteLine("--------------------------");
                Console.WriteLine("Player's Timed Post-Analysis");
                Console.WriteLine("(Within scope of player update)");
                Console.WriteLine("Elapsed time: " + gameTime.TotalGameTime.Seconds +" sec");
                Console.WriteLine("UserControlled: " + UserControlled);
                Console.WriteLine("--------------------------");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                debugTime = gameTime.TotalGameTime.Seconds;
            }
```

That's about it. Thanks for helping.

Comment: What method is this line of code in? Are you sure that method has been called prior to the internal references you mention?

Comment: It's in a method called ParseUpdateMessage(NetIncomingMessage msg).
And yes, as I call the references immediately after the code is called and continuously every 5 seconds both in the player class and outside of it.

Comment: You'll probably want to provide more code to help narrow down the problem. Could you start by providing the code for your Message object, how it's set, sent to client, and finally received by client. That should provide the necessary code path for this problem.

Comment: Could you post the code for the class and if needed strip out non-relevant methods?  I'm especially interested to see how this var is defined and exposed to other classes, plus the method you mentioned.

Comment: I feel your pain but unfortunately these type of problems are almost impossible to answer on this site. You don't know where the problem exists, so can't post the relevant code (there's nothing wrong with the single line that you've posted, obviously) and *we* will only be guessing until we see the problem. A better question might be 'how should I go about identifying and tracking obscure bugs'.

Comment: Edited to show where the code is instantiated, set, and referenced.

Comment: Is there only one player entity? Is player of id1 the same player entity through which you are printing out UserControlled?? I can only assume that if PlayerEntity of id1 has a UserControlled value as true when accessed outside of the player is not the same player entity through which you are printing a false value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As my comment above says, I can't tell you what is happening, but can only give advice on how to debug.

Firstly, you say you've checked this but ensure that you are setting the correct `UserControlled`. If it's a member of the class (assume it's a property?) then prefix it with `this.`

```
this.UserControlled = msg.ReadBoolean();
```

From what I understand in your question, `UserControlled` is *true* when interrogated inside the class, but *false* when queried from outside the class. This can only be two things:

1. You have two different properties, or the property is evaluating differently due to side effects.
2. You have two instances of your class

To investigate further, is your property doing anything clever - i.e. is it doing anything other that setting and getting a backing field?  Are you sure that you're using a single instance of your class?

Comment: Thanks! I was hoping by some miracle that someone would have a solution, but any help for debugging is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is difficult to answer, due to the lack of code, but at the same time, it's not practical to post all of your code anyway.

The most times I've done this on accident, would be declaring another variable in a different scope, and setting that one instead of the one I intended to.

So, it seems the code is only being set in that one area, but that also might be why your "Find all references" only come up with that one spot.  I would try to right click on both the `UserControlled` and `msg` variables and choose `Go to declaration` instead.  Maybe you'll find you're setting a different variable with the same name you weren't expecting.

If `UserControlled` is a property in a class, you can also try to set a breakpoint on it.  You can right click on the breakpoint and choose "When Hit..." and set it up to print the stack trace and value of it whenever its hit, instead of stopping execution (I'm assuming this is a game and you may not want to/easily be able to stop and continue execution).

Comment: Unfortunately, using the "Go to Definition" feature led to the intended position.